# Extract strings between special characters

Tags: regex, string, stringr, stringi

Please help me in extracting the string from this text like

1. id1:value1,id2:value2
2. id1:value1a,id2:value2a

from

**"[{id1:value1,id2:value2},{id1:value1a,id2:value2a}]"**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working codes

unlist(regmatches(text, gregexpr("\\{.*?\\}", text)))

unlist(regmatches(text, gregexpr("\\{([^}]+)\\}", text)))

Answer (score 0):

`{([^}]+)}` will find and capture anything that is inside `{ }`

You should include more detail in your question though and show that you have made an attempt at it yourself.

Comment: Thanks for throwing some light on the regex part as i understood a bit more.
 i found one more way to get it done, jotted down both.
unlist(regmatches(text, gregexpr("\\{.*?\\}", text)))
unlist(regmatches(text, gregexpr("\\{([^}]+)\\}", text)))